# Android - how do I change divider color of the overflow menu?

Tags: android, layout, menu, overflow

I want to change the color of the dividers in my overflow menu. I managed to do it using the following code. But I have realized the dividers in all the spinners of the app are also changed. Is there a way to change the color only for the overflow menu?

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"> 
         <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/MyDropDownListView</item>  
</style> 

<style name="MyDropDownListView" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
   <item name="android:divider">#bb0000</item> 
   <item name="android:dividerHeight">5dp</item>  
</style>
```